# Ignore MySQL Group By value

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

basically I'm having some troubles trying to group all rows by their **type** except the only which is called lets say "test", this one is meant to be ignored but displayed apart if its possible, but I can't really find a solution, thanks in advance!

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount) as 'amount' FROM history WHERE date = '$date' GROUP BY type
```

The query which is above is grouping all rows including the one I'm trying to ignore

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You explanation could use more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
GROUP BY type, IF(type = "test", id, 0)
```

Replace `id` with the primary key of the table.

When type is `test` this uses the primary key as a secondary grouping field, so all those rows will be in separate groups. For all other types, the secondary group will be equal for all items, so they don't get subgroups.